# Can an LCD be damaged by a low battery voltage?

Tags: voltage, lcd, battery-operated, damage

I've got a digital alarm clock where the battery got really low, to the point where the display was hardly viewable. I assume that the voltage must have really dropped. I put some new batteries in it, but a few of the segments of the display have stopped working. Has the low battery voltage likely done permanent damage to the LCD display?

It's the type of LCD found on a calculator, not a TV/monitor/phone type display.

Comment: I have done this to multiple devices multiple times with no apparent ill effects and I think a sane LCD driver should not have this failure mode. As far as I remember, LCDs are driven with AC and a DC of some magnitude in the driving signal is bad for them, but I neither know how much DC is bad nor if the statement holds true for modern ones. The most common failure mode for LCD displays seems to be a bad contact between the PCB and the LCD edge where the terminals are. But let's wait until someone more knowledgeable says something.

Comment: @fraxinus has the likely cause. Perhaps in replacing the battery, the LCD electrical path to the logic has flexed and disturbed the path to those few segments. A *zebra strip* often connects the LCD module to its electronic driver on a printed circuit board (google zebra strip). Re-seating this strip may restore those segments.

Comment: @glen_geek would that entail re-soldering something? Just had a quick look at the cost of electronics repairs, and it seems like it'll be cheaper do bin the clock and buy a brand new one (repair cost approx double the cost of a brand new one)

Comment: No, zebra strips are pressure contact, not soldered. If the LCD has shifted a tiny bit, the zebra strip may have moved, and simply needs re-positioning. These are extremely low-current, easy connections, but still cannot be open-circuit.

Comment: Got the back off but looks like it'll be getting scrapped. Either they've gone OTT with tightening up the screws that hold the PCB in place or they've glued and screwed it in place

Comment: @glen_geek, adding to your good advice on zebra strip: if the LCD still doesn't work, the zebra strips can be removed and the contacts on the PCB and LCD glass cleaned before refitting them. That's often helped in repairs I've done.

Comment: 9 times out of 10, electronics stops working because of connections, so zebra strips are a strong possibility. However, to your question, it's theoretically possible there's a low voltage failure mode in the driver that could damage the LCD. They must be driven with AC, to avoid electrolysing them. If at a low voltage, the driver clock stops, and it ends up providing DC, then that could kill the display, or at least, the driven segments.